# Angular 6 - Seconds to date in html

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there any way to convert seconds to date in the html template using Angular 6?

Such as:

`{{ dateInSeconds | secondsToDate }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Jihoon shared is the builted-in Angular pipe for dates, but as the Angular docs say, the number must represent the *miliseconds* of the date, not the *seconds*. To show it you should parse it to milliseconds first so in your case you could do something like this :

`{{dateInSeconds * 1000 | date:'dd/MM/yyyy(EEE) - hh:mmaaa'}}`

Here's the link for the Angular date pipe doc:
[Angular Date Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can use date pipeline in the template as well.

for example :

```
{{1535417068439 | date:'dd/MM/yyyy(EEE) - hh:mmaaa'}}
```

Comment: Do I need to import something? I'm getting `'Unable to convert "1533524400" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'`

Comment: @Sajeetharan I believe my situation is happening due to seconds being in string format. How can I convert it to a suitable format to perform the operation?

Comment: no string also should work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjbuav?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html